# How do you change sapi voice pitch mid sentence in vbscript?

Tags: vbscript, sapi

I'm trying to recreate daisy bell with vbs using sapi, but I have a portion of the song that's unpleasantly jarring:

```
yellow.Rate = 6
yellow.Speak "<pitch middle = '-10'/> Give."
yellow.Speak "<pitch middle = '-8'/> Me."
yellow.Speak "<pitch middle = '-5'/> Your."
```

Is there a way to adjust pitch mid sentence instead of separating lyrics by pitch so it can be sung more smoothly?

These are the attempts I've made, and although the lyrics are said more smoothly doing these gets rid of any pitch adjustments:

```
yellow.Speak "<pitch middle = '-10'> Give
           <pitch middle = '-8'> Me
            <pitch middle = '-5'> Your
            </pitch>
           </pitch>
          </pitch>."
```

and

```
yellow.Speak "<pitch middle = '-10'/> Give, <pitch middle = '-8'/> Me, <pitch middle = '-5'/> Your."
```

Comment: Suggest looking through [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms717077(v=vs.85)). Also, the notes of [Pitch Adjustment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms717237(v=vs.85)).

Comment: I tried implementing the example given in the second link, but kept on throwing compiler errors about not ending the string right. I don't really know how to transfer it into the sapi.Speak "<pitch = '#'/> words here" format

Answer (score 0):

Try it with "absmiddle". In the example below, the pitch change is easy to hear:

```
Set oSapi = CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
oSapi.Rate = 6
oSapi.Speak "<pitch absmiddle = '-10'/> Give, <pitch absmiddle = '+10'/> Me, <pitch absmiddle = '-10'/> Your."
```

Comment: I think it's sorta working, just need to readjust the pitches. Now it's starting off way higher than intended

Comment: I put in extreme values to be sure I could hear the difference. Hopefully you can adjust the values to the correct pitch.